# Find the Derivative of $\frac{1}{\cos^2(2x)+\sin^2(2x)}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Calculate the derivative of: $$\frac{1}{\cos^2(2x)+\sin^2(2x)}.$$ How would I calculate such a derivative?

Comment: Please show us some effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint:

Since $\cos^2(2x)+\sin^2(2x)=1$, you are left with $\frac{1}{1}=1$. Now what is the derivative of $1$?

Anytime you have the form $\cos^2(u)+\sin^2(u)$, it always equals $1$. Check out the pythagorean identities.

Comment: understand, thank you very much. It wasn't that hard.

Comment: @Krowskir No problem

Comment: By the way, if you somehow overlooked that fact and calculated the derivative, you would find it was zero. That tells us immediately the original function must be a constant.

Answer (score 2):

The denominator is identity in trigonometry and is 1 so you have constant term to find derivative of which should be zero.

Answer (score 2):

It is amusing to see we can use derivatives to prove that $f(x)=\cos^2x+\sin^2 x$ is constant, if you know that $(\cos x)'=-\sin x$ and $(\sin x)'=\cos x$.

Because $f'(x)=2\cos x (-\sin x) + 2\sin x \cos x = 0$.

More generally, if $f''(x)=-f(x)$,  we can conclude that $f(x)^2 + (f'(x))^2$ is constant.